# Is there an examble of a non additive base of natural numbers with ratio of two consecutive terms goes to 1?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Here $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$.

We say that a set $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ is an additive base of natural numbers if there is
a positive integer $h\in \mathbb{N}$ such that every natural number can be written as $a_1+\dots+a_h$ for some (not necessarily distinct) $a_i\in A\cup\{0\}$.

Some famous examples of such additive bases are the $k$-powers (Waring's problem) and the
set of primes including $1$ (a theorem by Schnirelmann).

All the examples I encountered so far had the same property. If $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ was
an additive base and $a_n$ was the $n$-th term of the set then
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= 1.$$

It wasn't very hard to prove that indeed this is true for every additive base.
Then I started to look the reverse direction. I tried to find a set
$A=\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ (the terms are in ascending order) with $a_1=1\in A$ and
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= 1$ which is not an additive base but I couldn't.

I would be glad if someone could enlightened me with such an example. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @lulu Note $1\in A$. But $1$ along with all multiples of $3$ works.

Comment: @Arthur  Ah, thank you.  Though the same principle works with a small modification (as you remark).

Comment: Are you allowed repeats when adding together up to $h$ elements of $A$?

Comment: @Arthur I think that the multiples of 3 along with 1 is an additive base with h=3.  I am trying to find a non additive base with these properties. Yes with repeats.

Comment: @Arthur note that every element of $\mathbb{N}$ is of the form $3n+\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2$ for some $\varepsilon_i\in\{0,1\}$, so every element of $\mathbb{N}$ is indeed a sum of at most $3$ elements from $1\cup 3\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Hence the question about repeats.

Comment: @Arthur have edited OP's post to clarify :) ... Iliopoulos, feel free of course to revert my edit if you wish, but hopefully this adds some clarity; nice question! (+1)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Thank you very much for the edit! It was my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $A(x)$ denotes the number of elements of $A$ less than $x$. A standard lemma says that an additive basis $A$ of order $h$ one has to have $A(x) \gg x^{1/h}$. In particular, the elements of $A$ can't grow significantly faster than $n^h$. But now simply choose a set where the terms grow faster than $n^h$ for any $h$ but still have the desired limit property $\lim a_{n+1}/a_n = 1$, e.g. take
$$a_n = \lfloor n^{\log \log n} \rfloor$$
for $n \ge 2$.

For a reference/proof of the "standard lemma" see Theorem 1 here: http://www.theoryofnumbers.com/melnathanson/pdfs/nath2010-138.pdf

Comment: thanks a lot for your immediate responce! Very nice counter examble indeed!